# C++ Using an auto-defined variable before knowing its type

Tags: c++, auto

I'm currently trying to use an auto-defined variable before knowing its type. Why? Because the type depends on the program input. If a user picks a certain distribution, the program will output values based on that distribution. Here's the code:

```
std::default_random_engine random_engine;
auto random;

if(from_dist)
{
    char* dist_name = strtok(distribution_name, "()");
    char* parameters = strtok(nullptr, "()");
    if(strcmp(dist_name, "gaussian") == 0)
    {
        double mean = atof(strtok(parameters, ","));
        double stddev = atof(strtok(nullptr, ","));
        std::normal_distribution<double> normal_distribution(mean, stddev);
        random = std::bind(normal_distribution, random_engine);
    }
        //TODO: Add more...
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid distribution. Known distributions:" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "\tgaussian(mean,stddev) - gaussian (aka normal) distributions" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

However, C++ doesn't allow me to use an auto variable in this fashion. Is there any alternative that allows me to use the following snippet (later on the execution), without having to repeat it for each possible distribution?

```
while(true) {
        std::string message(OBSERVATION);
        for (int i = 0; i < FEATURE_COUNT; i++)
            message += " " + ((int) random());

        send(sock, message.c_str(), strlen(message.c_str()), 0);
        if (wait_time_ms)
            sleep(wait_time_ms);
}
```

Comment: Will all of your random functions have the form of `double()`?

Comment: in general `auto` does not mean that the type is unknown. It also does not mean that it can be any type. It just means that the compiler can safe you from typing the type

Comment: Why are you binding a random `double` distribution and then casting all the results to `int`?

Comment: Use `std::function`

Comment: @NathanOliver yes they'll be all in the form of double.

Comment: @Caleth I had another thing in my head the first time I wrote that. Its not supposed to be casted into int. Fixed.

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with what is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your title and description clearly indicate you were asking about what you thought will solve your issue, rather than about the exact particular issue (which is how to define a callable object without knowing its exact type). Just like the problem in the meta post. It's a good thing you included as much code as you did, or the answer you would have gotten would have left you thinking you can't progress.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok, will do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `random` (if I read your code correctly) is to become a callable object.

You can solve your problem by making `random` a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object with the correct signature:

```
std::function<double()> random;
```

Comment: Apart from on doing so; the function will be using UB because the object it's being called on goes out of scope; but then that's an existing problem in OP's code anyway :)

Comment: @UKMonkey Oh yeah that's true. A big oops.

Comment: @UKMonkey - What object? Doesn't the whole thing decay copy the arguments?

Comment: @StoryTeller didn't use a pointer to object ... yes.  Sorry; so used to my `std::bind(delete, new Derp())()` I forgot it does a copy

Comment: Well thank you for the answer! I'm getting kind of mindblown by what modern C++ has to offer! I now think I shouldn't have said my thesis coordinator that I was fluent in C++, cause visibly, there's still so much I don't know!

Answer (score 3):

The type of a variable declared with `auto` *must* be known at *compile time*. If you really want the ability to store values of different types with a single variable name, take a look at [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). However, it does also look like you don't even need to use multiple types. If I understand your code correctly, `random` should be declared as an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object with the correct signature.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `auto` you must initialize the variable so the compiler can deduce the type.  Since you're not sure what type you are going to have you can't use it.  What you can do though since all of your random generators will have the form of `double()` is use a `std::function<double()>`.  This will let you declare `random` in the scope you need but allow you to assign to it the generator you want.  That would look like

```
std::default_random_engine random_engine;
std::function<double()> random;

if(from_dist)
{
    char* dist_name = strtok(distribution_name, "()");
    char* parameters = strtok(nullptr, "()");
    if(strcmp(dist_name, "gaussian") == 0)
    {
        double mean = atof(strtok(parameters, ","));
        double stddev = atof(strtok(nullptr, ","));
        random = [=]()
        { 
            static std::normal_distribution<double> normal_distribution(mean, stddev);
            return normal_distribution(random_engine);
        };
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: That `static` is a bit nasty.  It means that it will only work the first time this function is called.

Comment: @MartinBonner How so?  The static stops the the distribution from being recreated every time the function is called but it is still there and mutable.

Comment: Yes, but it will only be initialized the first time, so second call with a different mean and standard deviation won't get you what you wanted.

Comment: @MartinBonner The OP is never calling it with a different mean and standard deviation.  The set it once in the decision making process and then use the generator after that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NathanOliver! Too bad I can't signal both answers as "accepted"!